# Converting HTML emails to "Well Formed XHTML Code"

Tags: php, data-structures, xsd, dataform, mechanicalturk

I've trying to submit html emails to amazon's mechanical turk using the questionform xml data scheme.  I'm having issues converting the html emails into well formed html data.  I just input a script to grab it from my table and print the data inside the  tags of the  html email, but as you can see below, it's terribly formed and will not pass to mechanical turk - I've had to send the data as htmlentities() until now and this makes it difficult for HIT workers to easily solve my issues.  Here's an example of how not well formed the data is - any tips on how to send this data through mechanical turk (php) or convert it to well formed html data would be appreciated.

```
<body text="#333333" bgcolor="#ffffff" link="#073064" vlink="#073064"
alink="#073064">
<a name="top"></a>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" bgcolor="#f4f2ee">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
  <td valign="top" align="left">
   <table width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
       <tbody>
               <tr>
                       <td style="background-color:#e8e6dd;background-image:none;background-repeat:repeat;background-position:top left;background-attachment:scroll;font-size:10px;color:#948765;line-height:200%;font-family:verdana;" >Email not displaying correctly?
<a
href="http://sitepointcom.cmail2.com/t/y/l/cvkit/ddktkrydd/r" style="color:#948765;" >View
it in your browser.</a></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                       <td height="93" bgcolor="#ff6501"
background="http://i1.cmail2.com/ei/y/4D/1C6/61A/231513/csimport/banner-tt_0.jpg">
                               <h1 style="font-size:30px;text-transform:lowercase;line-height:16px;color:#ffffff;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;text-indent:63px;margin-top:0;padding-top:29px;" >SitePoint <span
style="font-size: 17px; display: block; text-indent: 164px; color:
rgb(248, 255, 225); margin-top: 5px;">Tech Times</span></h1>
                       </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                       <td height="20" bgcolor="#C64F00" style="color:#e7fabd;font-family:arial;font-size:13px;" >
                               <span
id="Date" style="float:right;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;" ><strong>Issue 309:</strong> September 21,
2010&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;Tips, Tricks, News and Reviews for Web Coders
                       </td>
               </tr>
       </tbody
</table>
   <table width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="5" height="10"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td width="10"></td>
      <td rowspan="2" width="380" valign="top">
           <table width="100%" border="0"
style="font-family:Verdana,Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px;
color:#000">
             <tr>
               <td>
            <a name='2'></a><h2 style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;color:#C64F00;font-family:arial;line-height:110%;" >
 Introduction
</h2>
<p>
 <img src="http://i2.cmail2.com/ei/y/4D/1C6/61A/231513/csimport/lisa-lang_1.jpg" height="119"
align="left" width="130" border="0" alt="Lisa Lang" /><strong><em>Sal
</em>Tech Timers! Every week we aim to provide you with a feast of tech
geekyness -- but this issue is particularly HUGE, with goodies for
everyone. This week, I'm proud to present our latest SitePoint release <a
href="http://sitepointcom.cmail2.com/t/y/l/cvkit/ddktkrydd/y"><em>Host Your Web Site in
the Cloud</em></a><em> </em>by web evangelist Jeff Barr. Everything you
need to know about cloud computing -- and how to make it work for you --
can be found in this book. </strong>
</p>
<p>
 In celebration of this <a
href="http://sitepointcom.cmail2.com/t/y/l/cvkit/ddktkrydd/j">release</a>, we'll be
running a live webinar with Jeff Barr, Kevin Yank, Lucas Chan, and Louis
Simoneau. The webinar will begin at 9:00 a.m. (Australian Eastern Standard
Time) on Wednesday, 22nd September. For those in the US, the meeting starts
at 4:00 p.m. (Pacific Standard Time) on Tuesday, 21st September. Places are
limited, so hurry to register now for free <a
href="http://sitepointcom.cmail2.com/t/y/l/cvkit/ddktkrydd/t">here</a>!
</p>
<p>
 In the meantime, to get you in the mood for the wonderful world of cloud
computing, have a read through Toby Tremayne's latest addition to his
series &quot;What Cloud Computing Can Mean for Your Business.&quot; Toby
shows you how to get started, and introduces a wide range of handy (and
free) applications.
</p>
<p>
 Next, the other big news of the week was the release of IE9. Craig
Buckler takes a look at its interface, including some new features and
development tools of this &quot;<a
href="http://sitepointcom.cmail2.com/t/y/l/cvkit/ddktkrydd/i">Beauty of the Web</a>.&quot;
</p>
<p>
 And last but not least, James Edwards has some fun with shadows for
complex shapes. He shows you how to create a fancy solution in CSS, even
managing to make it work on all modern browsers.
</p>
<p>
 That should keep you busy until next week. As always, feel free to come
over and join the discussions in our <a
href="http://sitepointcom.cmail2.com/t/y/l/cvkit/ddktkrydd/d">forums</a>.
</p>
<p>
 Keep rocking!
</p>
<hr color="#c5b172" size="1" />
<h2 style="line-height:1.2em;" ><a
href="http://sitepointcom.cmail2.com/t/y/l/cvkit/ddktkrydd/h"
style="color:red">Over 80% of Small Businesses Use Email Marketing ... But
Only a Handful Use It Effectively</a></h2><a
href="http://sitepointcom.cmail2.com/t/y/l/cvkit/ddktkrydd/k"><img
src="http://i3.cmail2.com/ei/y/4D/1C6/61A/231513/csimport/infusionsoft120x100-em20_2.jpg"
width="120" height="100" align="right" hspace="5" vspace="0" border="0"
/></a><p>Discover the secrets to effective, profitable email marketing
when you download the free report <em>"Email Marketing 2.0: the Three
Techniques That Will Actually Make a Difference In Your Email
Marketing."</em></p><p>Hint: this report does NOT cover subject line
suggestions, SPAM words to avoid, best time of day to send, or how to
address your contacts.</p><a
href="http://sitepointcom.cmail2.com/t/y/l/cvkit/ddktkrydd/u"
style="color:red"><strong>Don't wait -- Download your free copy
now!</strong></a><div
style="margin-bottom:2em;padding-bottom:1em;border-bottom: 1px dotted
#C5B172;"></div>
<p><strong>Summary</strong></p>
<ul style="font-size:110%;line-height:150%;" ><li><a
href="#2">Introduction</a></li><li><a href="#5">What Cloud Computing Can
Mean for Your Business, Part II: Starting Your Cloud
Infrastructure</a></li><li><a href="#7">The IE9 Beta Review</a></li><li><a
href="#8">Creating Shadows Around Polygons in CSS</a></li><li><a
href="#11">New Technical Articles</a></li><li><a href="#12">Techy Forum
Threads</a></li><li><a href="#13">More Techy Blog Entries</a></li></ul>
<div style="margin-bottom:2em;padding-bottom:1em;border-bottom-width:1px;border-bottom-style:dotted;border-bottom-color:#C5B172;" ></div>
<a name='5'></a><h2 style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;color:#C64F00;font-family:arial;line-height:110%;" >
 Starting Your Cloud Infrastructure
</h2>
<h3 style="font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;color:#C64F00;font-family:arial;line-height:110%;" >
 What Cloud Computing Can Mean for Your Business, Part II
</h3>
<div>
 Starting out, what do we need? We have to be able to communicate
with our customers and suppliers, so we need email, perhaps instant
messaging. If we have overseas or long distance clients, some kind of VOIP
phone would help to keep costs down.
</div>
<div>
 We must ensure that anything we're working on is properly backed
up from the business plan to product concepts and beyond. Any loss
of data could be crucial when getting your product or service to market at
the right time. Keeping an eye on our schedule is vital to make sure
important events, tasks, and meetings are managed.<br />
</div>
<div>
 There's a lot more to address, but this much is enough to get us
up and running so we can get about the business of doing business.
&#160;But if you're not an IT person and you don't know how to
setup email servers or backup systems, where do you begin?
</div>
<h3>
 Email
</h3>
<div>
 Google has been a provider of innovative products in the cloud for some
time, but many are unaware just how powerful these applications can be.
Gmail, for example, offers free email accounts with enormous amounts of
storage, and an easy-to-use interface. Your email can be accessed from
anywhere, you never have to delete as everything can be archived, and
backups are taken care of for you. The only issue is that you may want to
avoid sending emails to a big potential client from an anonymous, free
Gmail account; to make a proper impression, you need to be able to have
your own email address under your company name.
</div>
<div>
 Google can still help you here, though; you can actually use the Gmail
system with your own domain name. As long as you have a <a
mce_href="http://sitepointcom.cmail2.com/t/y/l/cvkit/ddktkrydd/o"
href="http://sitepointcom.cmail2.com/t/y/l/cvkit/ddktkrydd/o">domain</a>, you can purchase a
Google Apps for Business account for the trifling sum of US$50 a year,
which lets you transfer your email hosting to Google's servers.
It's a very simple process, and once done you have full IMAP
access to your email from anywhere in the world, with a guarantee of
availability and uptime that few can compete with certainly not in a
small business.
</div>
<div>
 The cost increases as you add more email accounts, but it's still
less than you'd pay to host a server with your own email software on
it. You can set up a normal email client like Outlook or Apple mail to use
the server, or use the user-friendly Gmail interface on the Web. This
means that no matter what happens, you'll always have access to email and
the ability to send from your own email address, even if your personal
computers fail. There are more great benefits to using Google Apps, but
we'll explore those in the next article. For now, check out <a
mce_href="http://sitepointcom.cmail2.com/t/y/l/cvkit/ddktkrydd/b" href="http://sitepointcom.cmail2.com/t/y/l/cvkit/ddktkrydd/b">Google Apps
for Business</a> to get up and running with your email.
</div>
<h3>
 Messaging
</h3>
```

Note:  I removed a lot of code here in the middle so that it would allow me to post the size of this document.

```
       <hr color="#c5b172" size="1" /><h2
style="font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;color:#C64F00;font-family:arial;line-height:110%;"><a
name='11'></a>New Technical Articles</h2><h3><a
href="http://sitepointcom.cmail2.com/t/y/l/cvkit/ddktkrydd/tu"
style="color:#7B7B94"><strong>CSS3 Border Images for Beautiful, Flexible
Boxes</strong></a></h3>
<p><img src="http://i8.cmail2.com/ei/y/4D/1C6/61A/231513/csimport/author_louis_lazaris_17.jpg"
hspace="3" alt="Louis Lazaris" align="left" width="67" height="80" />Among
the raft of CSS3 features gaining increasing levels of browser support, the
border-image property is often overlooked. In this article, Louis gives us
the lowdown on what it is and how to use it.</p>
<p align="right"><a
href="http://sitepointcom.cmail2.com/t/y/l/cvkit/ddktkrydd/il"
style="color:#7B7B94">Full Story...</a></p><h3><a
href="http://sitepointcom.cmail2.com/t/y/l/cvkit/ddktkrydd/ir"
style="color:#7B7B94"><strong>HTML5 and Even Fancier
Forms</strong></a></h3>
<p><img src="http://i9.cmail2.com/ei/y/4D/1C6/61A/231513/csimport/author_tim_connell_18.jpg"
hspace="3" alt="Tim Connell" align="left" width="67" height="80" />Tim
Connell, co-author of SitePoint's Fancy Form Design, takes a look at
the new form input types available in HTML5, and gives you the skinny on
which ones you can start using right now.</p>
<p align="right"><a
href="http://sitepointcom.cmail2.com/t/y/l/cvkit/ddktkrydd/iy"
style="color:#7B7B94">Full Story...</a></p>
<h2
style="font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;color:#C64F00;font-family:arial;line-height:110%;margin-top:2em;padding-top:1em;border-top:
1px dotted #C5B172;"><a name='12'></a>Techy Forum Threads</h2><ul
class="forums" style="margin-left:18px;padding-left:0;" ><li><a
href="http://sitepointcom.cmail2.com/t/y/l/cvkit/ddktkrydd/ij"
style="color:#7B7B94">How do you organize your CSS?</a> in CSS</li><li><a
href="http://sitepointcom.cmail2.com/t/y/l/cvkit/ddktkrydd/it"
style="color:#7B7B94">Jack of all Trades...</a> in .NET</li><li><a
href="http://sitepointcom.cmail2.com/t/y/l/cvkit/ddktkrydd/ii"
style="color:#7B7B94">Personification of software: The contest</a> in
General Chat</li></ul>
<hr color="#c5b172" size="1" /><h2
style="font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;color:#C64F00;font-family:arial;line-height:110%;"><a
name='13'></a>More Techy Blog Entries</h2><p style="font-size:80%;color:#aea194;" >Web Tech</p><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
border="0" width="100%"><tbody><tr>
                               <td valign="top"><img
src="http://i10.cmail2.com/ei/y/4D/1C6/61A/231513/csimport/nlblog_19.gif" width="16"
height="19" /></td>
                               <td width="7"></td>
                               <td style="font-family:verdana;font-size:13px;" >
                                       <a
href="http://sitepointcom.cmail2.com/t/y/l/cvkit/ddktkrydd/id"
style="color:#7B7B94">The Threat to Software Freedom</a>
                               </td>
                       </tr><tr>
                                       <td colspan="2"></td>
                                       <td><font size="-2" style="color:#AEA193;" >1 comment</td>
                               </tr><tr>
                               <td height="3"></td>
                       </tr><tr>
                               <td valign="top"><img
src="http://i10.cmail2.com/ei/y/4D/1C6/61A/231513/csimport/nlblog_19.gif" width="16"
height="19" /></td>
                               <td width="7"></td>
                               <td style="font-family:verdana;font-size:13px;" >
                                       <a
href="http://sitepointcom.cmail2.com/t/y/l/cvkit/ddktkrydd/ih"
style="color:#7B7B94">Apple: Stuff Ups, Mistakes, and Finally Moving
Forward?</a>
                               </td>
                       </tr><tr>
                                       <td colspan="2"></td>
                                       <td><font size="-2" style="color:#AEA193;" >19 comments</td>
                               </tr><tr>
                               <td height="3"></td>
                       </tr><tr>
                               <td valign="top"><img
src="http://i10.cmail2.com/ei/y/4D/1C6/61A/231513/csimport/nlblog_19.gif" width="16"
height="19" /></td>
                               <td width="7"></td>
                               <td style="font-family:verdana;font-size:13px;" >
                                       <a
href="http://sitepointcom.cmail2.com/t/y/l/cvkit/ddktkrydd/ik"
style="color:#7B7B94">Behind the Geek Out Scenes: Fancy Fonts and Jaunty
Input Fields</a>
                               </td>
                       </tr><tr>
                                       <td colspan="2"></td>
                                       <td><font size="-2" style="color:#AEA193;" >12 comments</td>
                               </tr><tr>
                               <td height="3"></td>
                       </tr></tbody></table><p style="font-size:80%;color:#aea194;" >JavaScript, CSS</p><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
border="0" width="100%"><tbody><tr>
                               <td valign="top"><img
src="http://i10.cmail2.com/ei/y/4D/1C6/61A/231513/csimport/nlblog_19.gif" width="16"
height="19" /></td>
                               <td width="7"></td>
                               <td style="font-family:verdana;font-size:13px;" >
                                       <a
href="http://sitepointcom.cmail2.com/t/y/l/cvkit/ddktkrydd/iu"
style="color:#7B7B94">High-performance String Concatenation in
JavaScript</a>
                               </td>
                       </tr><tr>
                                       <td colspan="2"></td>
                                       <td><font size="-2" style="color:#AEA193;" >11 comments</td>
                               </tr><tr>
                               <td height="3"></td>
                       </tr></tbody></table><p style="font-size:80%;color:#aea194;" >Web
Design</p><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"
width="100%"><tbody><tr>
                               <td valign="top"><img
src="http://i10.cmail2.com/ei/y/4D/1C6/61A/231513/csimport/nlblog_19.gif" width="16"
height="19" /></td>
                               <td width="7"></td>
                               <td style="font-family:verdana;font-size:13px;" >
                                       <a
href="http://sitepointcom.cmail2.com/t/y/l/cvkit/ddktkrydd/dl"
style="color:#7B7B94">WordPress Trademark Transferred To WordPress
Foundation</a>
                               </td>
                       </tr><tr>
                                       <td colspan="2"></td>
                                       <td><font size="-2" style="color:#AEA193;" >2 comments</td>
                               </tr><tr>
                               <td height="3"></td>
                       </tr></tbody></table><p style="font-size:80%;color:#aea194;" >Community</p><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"
width="100%"><tbody><tr>
                               <td valign="top"><img
src="http://i10.cmail2.com/ei/y/4D/1C6/61A/231513/csimport/nlblog_19.gif" width="16"
height="19" /></td>
                               <td width="7"></td>
                               <td style="font-family:verdana;font-size:13px;" >
                                       <a
href="http://sitepointcom.cmail2.com/t/y/l/cvkit/ddktkrydd/dr"
style="color:#7B7B94">Important People With Things to Say</a>
                               </td>
                       </tr><tr>
                               <td height="3"></td>
                       </tr></tbody></table><hr color="#c5b172" size="1" />
      </td>
      <td width="10"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td width="10"></td>
      <td width="20"
background="http://i5.cmail2.com/ei/y/4D/1C6/61A/231513/csimport/vertical-rule-bg_14.gif"></td>
      <td width="180" valign="bottom" style="color:#000000;font-family:verdana;font-size:13px;" >
<div id="subscribe">
 <h2 style="font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;color:#073064;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:110%;" >
   Follow SitePoint on..
 </h2>
<ul style="margin-left:5px;list-style-type:none;list-style-position:outside;list-style-image:none;padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" >
 <li style="font-size:15px;" >
   <img src="http://i1.cmail2.com/ei/y/4D/1C6/61A/231513/csimport/subs-nl_20.gif"
border="0" height="27" width="27" align="bottom" alt="Newsletters" /><a
style="margin-left:5px; text-decoration:none; font-weight:400"
href="http://sitepointcom.cmail2.com/t/y/l/cvkit/ddktkrydd/dy">Newsletters</a>
</li>
 <li style="font-size:15px;" >
   <img src="http://i2.cmail2.com/ei/y/4D/1C6/61A/231513/csimport/subs-tw_21.gif"
border="0" height="27" width="27" align="bottom" alt="Twitter" /><a
style="margin-left:5px; text-decoration:none; font-weight:400"
href="http://sitepointcom.cmail2.com/t/y/l/cvkit/ddktkrydd/dj" rel="nofollow">Twitter</a>
</li>
 <li style="font-size:15px;" >
   <img src="http://i3.cmail2.com/ei/y/4D/1C6/61A/231513/csimport/subs-m_22.gif" border="0"
height="27" width="27" align="bottom" alt="Mobile" /><a
style="margin-left:5px; text-decoration:none; font-weight:400"
href="http://sitepointcom.cmail2.com/t/y/l/cvkit/ddktkrydd/dt">Mobile</a>
</li>
 <li style="font-size:15px;" >
   <img src="http://i4.cmail2.com/ei/y/4D/1C6/61A/231513/csimport/subs-pod_23.gif"
border="0" height="27" width="27" align="bottom" alt="Podcast" /><a
style="margin-left:5px; text-decoration:none; font-weight:400"
href="http://sitepointcom.cmail2.com/t/y/l/cvkit/ddktkrydd/di">Podcast</a>
</li>
 <li style="font-size:15px;" >
   <img src="http://i5.cmail2.com/ei/y/4D/1C6/61A/231513/csimport/subs-rss_24.gif"
border="0" height="27" width="27" align="bottom" alt="RSS" /><a
style="margin-left:5px; text-decoration:none; font-weight:400"
href="http://sitepointcom.cmail2.com/t/y/l/cvkit/ddktkrydd/dd">RSS</a>
</li>
 <li style="font-size:15px;" >
   <img src="http://i6.cmail2.com/ei/y/4D/1C6/61A/231513/csimport/subs-fb_25.gif"
border="0" height="27" width="27" align="bottom" alt="Facebook" /><a
style="margin-left:5px; text-decoration:none; font-weight:400"
href="http://sitepointcom.cmail2.com/t/y/l/cvkit/ddktkrydd/dh" rel="nofollow">Facebook</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
                       <h2
style="font-size:15px;font-weight:bold;color:#C64F00;font-family:arial;line-height:110%;">Help
Your Friends Out</h2>
               <p>People you care about can benefit from the wealth of information on
new
                       and maturing technologies available on the Internet. Help them learn
                       how to do it by forwarding them this issue of the Tech Times!</p>
               <!--[if gte mso 0]><div style="display:none;" ><![endif]-->
               <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#F9990C">
                       <tr>
                               <td colspan="3" height="3" bgcolor="#C2721C"></td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                               <td colspan="3" height="10"></td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                               <td width="10"></td>
                               <td style="color:#ffffff;font-family:verdana;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;" >Send this to a friend</td>
                               <td width="20"></td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                               <td colspan="3" height="5"></td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                               <td width="10"></td>
                               <td style="font-family:verdana;font-size:13px;" >
                                       <form autocomplete="on"
action="http://www.sitepoint.com/newsletter/forward" method="get"
style="margin: 0pt;">
                                       <input name="newsletterid" value="3" type="hidden">
                                       <input name="fromemail" value="rcavezza@gmail.com" type="hidden">
                                       <input name="issuenum" value="309" type="hidden">
                                       <input autocomplete="on" name="email" value="friend@example.com"
style="width: 120px;" type="text">
                                       <br />
                                       <input autocomplete="on" name="Send" value="Send" type="submit">
                                       </form>
                               </td>
                               <td width="20"></td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                               <td colspan="3" height="10"></td>
                       </tr>
               </table>
               <!--[if gte mso 0]></div><![endif]-->
      </td>
      <td width="10"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="5" height="20"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="5" height="10" bgcolor="#9999BC"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#D7D7E5"></td>
      <td bgcolor="#D7D7E5" colspan="4" style="font-family:verdana;font-size:10px;color:#5e5e91;" >
       <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
style="font-size:12px">
        <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td width="100%" height="10" bgcolor="#D7D7E5"></td>
           <td rowspan="3" bgcolor="#032a5c" style="color:#FFF;font-size:12px;text-align:center;" >
             We send this newsletter using Campaign Monitor<br/>
<br/>
             <a
href="http://sitepointcom.cmail2.com/t/y/l/cvkit/ddktkrydd/dk"><img
src="http://i7.cmail2.com/ei/y/4D/1C6/61A/231513/csimport/cm-passive-200x125_26.png" width="200"
height="125" hspace="10" border="0" alt="Campaign Monitor"/></a>
           </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td style="font-size:12x!important;font-family:arial,
verdana;" >
            <p style="font-weight:bold;color:#353553;" >You are
subscribed as: <br>
<span style="font-size:13px;color:#CE6E11;font-weight:700;" ><code>rcavezza@gmail.com</code></span></p>
            <ul>
             <li><a href="http://sitepointcom.cmail2.com/t/y/u/cvkit/ddktkrydd/"
style="color:#7B7B94">Unsubscribe</a> from this list.</li>
             <li><a href="http://sitepointcom.cmail2.com/t/y/l/cvkit/ddktkrydd/du"
style="color:#7B7B94">Manage your subscriptions</a>.</li>
             <li><a href="http://sitepointcom.cmail2.com/t/y/l/cvkit/ddktkrydd/hl"
style="color:#7B7B94">View the newsletter archives</a>.</li>
            </ul>
            <p>
             <span style="font-weight:bold;color:#353553;" >Mailing
Address:</span><br />
        <span style="font-size:12px;" >48 Cambridge St, Collingwood, VIC,
3066 Australia</span>
            </p>
            <p><strong><span style="color:#353553;" >Phone:</span> +61 3
9090 8200</strong></p>
           </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td height="10" bgcolor="#D7D7E5"></td>
          </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<img src="https://cmail2.com/t/y/o/cvkit/ddktkrydd/o.gif"  width="1" height="1" border="0" style="height:1px !important;width:1px !important;border-width:0 !important;margin-top:0 !important;margin-bottom:0 !important;margin-right:0 !important;margin-left:0 !important;padding-top:0 !important;padding-bottom:0 !important;padding-right:0 !important;padding-left:0 !important;" ></body>
```

***EDIT:  Just changed it to fix the issues below, and it's still not passing the validation test - any additional steps I should take/try?***

Comment: That's way better, but you still have to use something like tidy unless you create valid HTML. Your are missing the HTML, HEAD, BODY open tags and the HTML closing tag. A HR doesn't have a COLOR or SIZE attribute. On some IMG you have not ALT and so on. So create valid output OR use tidy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not that badly formed. Just call [quoted_printable_decode()](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-decode.php) on it first.

**edit:** well, it solves a few problems, but it is still misformed as `*********`. Whatever possessed them not to quote whole lists of style declarations?

**edit2:** Ah, Bob removed the quotes all on his own. I assume with leaving the quotes there & quoted printable decode it would be solved.

Comment: This returns some interesting results - is there another function I should also use on it to supplement?  It does most of the job but here's one example <div styleşckground: #99ca3c;>

Comment: @Bob: it will return utf8 afaik, you may need to user `utf8_decode()` or the `iconv()` library if that's not the character set you're working in.

Comment: Perfect - I'm going to store these in a different way (had issues storing the files earlier) and then use this code - hopefully this will solve my issues - thanks!

Comment: I was able to fix this based on the errors before, but it's still not passing inspection through the php document - any ideas? - note - new email reformed above (with your help, thanks again!)

Comment: There's some opening & ending tag mismatch, but nothing really serious, so clearing up _why_ it doesn't pass inspection might be in order.

Answer (score 0):

Yea that looks like a mess, have you looked into or tried something like [htmlPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)?

There are a few others, but I do not know them as the only one I ever used was the htmlPurifier, but you may want to look into that (if that is what you are asking for).

Comment: Maybe, anything to help clean this up, lol.  I'm looking into it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tidy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) to repair your HTML. But it looks very bad so you should start with fixing the script that produces the HTML before.

On a windows machine you might have to add or uncomment the following line in your `php.ini` to be able to use it:

```
extension=php_tidy.dll
```

Some very basic [example from the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/de/tidy.cleanrepair.php):

```
$html = '<p>test</I>';

$tidy = tidy_parse_string($html);
$tidy->cleanRepair();

echo $tidy;
```

This will output the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>test</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you send me some resources or pages with sample implementations of tidy with php?

Comment: My tidy converts this `style` mess to: `<li style="list-style-position:" list-style-image:="" margin-bottom:="">`. There are limits even to tidy :(

Comment: I take out some of the quotation marks prior to inserting into the database - perhaps if I perform this before changing the original code it may help a bit.

Comment: @Bob: erm, indeed..... why would you remove the quotes prior to inserting it into the database? That only leads to (this kind of) trouble....

Comment: A bad case of using scotch tape as a band aid because I was too lazy to go to the store